# Achievement icons have skewed vertical alignment on Chrome on Android mobile today?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, mobile-web

Something seems to have skewed the vertical alignment of the icons on my achievement page today.

[image: icon broked image]

Update 14 May 2018: It happened again, so I assume the fix is going to be the CDN purge again?

[image]

Comment: How about now? I've issued a purge on the CDN for the sprite file.

Comment: @Oded - that has corrected the issue. Thanks.

Comment: I think the general recommendation is to post a new bug report if the problem comes back.

Comment: Oops - thanks @Catija. I probably can't from here - I'm in a foreign country with limited connectivity. But they'll probably fix it before I get home.

Comment: Ah. Fair. I've poked Nick in the comments on his answer. :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm sure some people have seen a few instances of this, so a little update (we got some more info yesterday):

There is a content refresh race we're not quite able to explain yet but are tracking down. The logs prove it's happening. Somehow it's serving old content with the new hash even though our build process should prevent this (we deploy all new static content to all servers before any code/hash changes to any servers). We're digging into how in the hell this is happening, mostly because it's driving us nuts.

Comment: Isn't it fastly's fault? (I don't think it happened before you switched over to them)

Comment: Was totally happening before fastly.

Comment: @oded weird, wasn't reported before. Well... good luck hunting that bug down, I have a feeling it's an evasive one. :)

Comment: It was happening before Fastly, but it's far more likely with Fastly, likely due to more cache locations and local purge rates overall. I have identified the issue, and we'll get a fix in next week (this will require build changes).

Comment: (psst, someone has a question about exceptional here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38854251/nullreferenceexception-inside-exceptional-logging oh, and I created a tag for the library)

Comment: Hey... looks like this may have recurred, see edit to question. :D