# Incorrect icons on hot network questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, hot-questions, icons

I see the same problem has occurred in the past, the most-linked one being [Wrong icons in the "hot network questions" column](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299205)

Is this happening for anyone else?

I've marked the icons I could recognize as incorrect.

This exists on every page, is on both chrome and firefox (from Ubuntu 16.04), and persists after hard-refreshes in each.

Edit: The icons in Meta's Hot Network Questions tab appear to be consistently accurate. Every other page I checked (including Unix, Workplace, English Language & Usage, Money, and Sci-fi) have a handful of incorrect ones, even for some of the same questions that are displayed correctly in Meta.

Further note: if it matters, the icons are also incorrect in the drop down community-search feature on the right end of the header. Again, they appear correct on this Meta page, and incorrect on all other pages I've checked.
Some of the ones that are consistently incorrect:

- computational science
- constructed languages
- movies and TV
- raspberri pi
- rpg
- russian language
- science fiction and fantasy
- sitecore
- skeptics
- super user
- latex
- workplace

That distribution seems skewed, but I may just be disproportionately familiar with the sites at the end of the alphabet. Many others could be wrong, those are just the ones I could recognize.

[image]

Last edit: apparently my Google skills were lacking - [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374126/hot-network-questions-have-broken-icons) was asked an hour prior.

Comment: Wasn't that asked very recently?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I don't see a question about it on the "newest questions" list for the "bug" tag.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ a google search of `site:meta.stackexchange.com incorrect icons hot network questions` doesn't turn up anything for the last six months

Comment: Seems fixed now, as far as I can tell.

Comment: For me it's been correct on meta, but remains incorrect on other sites.

Comment: Ah, yep, I see it too. The icons are still wrong on SO main.

Comment: I think there's something wrong with the [big image full of favicons](https://cdn.sstatic.net/img/favicons-sprite16.png). A bunch of them are out of order or missing.

Comment: The ones I've listed as being wrong, are all only off by one in that list. I wonder why everything isn't shifted though

Comment: Also seen in the accounts list in the profile Activity page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/118ZA.png

Comment: It also shows up in the site dropdown: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypTR0.png

Comment: Ah, there was a prior post about this, on SO's meta as opposed to SE https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374126/hot-network-questions-have-broken-icons. This one has more details in body and comments, but given that it's a known and recurring problem, that probably doesn't matter.

Comment: We're renaming a site and changing its favicon and a couple of other sites' icons... messing with them always causes this for a few people. We're poking at it and it should be fixed soon.

Comment: @Catija out of curiosity, which site?

Comment: @muru Health to Medical Sciences.

Comment: @Adam this wasn't fixed. It happens any time a new site is being launched, e.g. [today](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389214/hot-network-questions-icons-do-not-match-the-sites-to-which-they-link). Can you please remove the completed tag, so that hopefully one day it will get a real fix?

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard It's not worth anybody's time to chase down at the moment, given that this is something that (sometimes) happens and has a chance to even happen at all approximately a handful of times a year if I'm being generous. I do have the cache purge documented internally, so we can be more proactive about it in the future.

Answer (score 8):

Apparently [we've been looking into this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281995/achievement-icons-have-skewed-vertical-alignment-on-chrome-on-android-mobile-tod) for a while now. :) But, the core problem remains the same - sometimes some CDN nodes end up caching an old image with the new cachebreaker and everything goes out of whack.

I'll see if we can dig more into it soon<sup>TM</sup>, but in the meantime, please feel free to [blame caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com). The problem should resolve itself one way or another in some time.

Comment: It's been like this for at least a week now... slightly maddening, really.  HNQ sidebar is painful to try to skim when the icons are all completely wrong.  Plenty of question titles need the context of the site they belong to in order to efficiently just parse the meaning of what's being asked.

Comment: @J... Sorry about that. How about now? Are the icons still messed up?

Comment: Nice, yes, it seems they're good now.  Was only on SO and maybe a few other sites - others were ok but now everything seems in order.  Thanks!

Comment: @J... Glad to hear it!

Comment: Looks like this still happens.

Comment: @Adam, yes ^ but now they are [missing for Firefox in North America](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8603162#8603162) but present everywhere for Chrome browser.

Comment: ... and fixed. Thanks, gremlins (or Adam).

Comment: @Rob nothing was ever really fixed. This keeps happening **every time a new site is launched**.