# Incorrect favicons

Tags: bug, status-completed, favicon

The favicons in the HNQ list (and also in "Your Communities") are strangely incorrect, as if they were vertically displaced:

[image]

It's happening to me in all major browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari etc).

Comment: I can't reproduce this. What OS are you on? Are you going through a corporate proxy that's MITM'ing your traffic?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica MacOS 10.13, all browsers. And no, just a regular internet connection.

Comment: It's a CDN caching issue, it happens from time to time: [Incorrect icons on hot network questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315468/incorrect-icons-on-hot-network-questions). Just wait a while, and it will be fixed.

Comment: We have to make one more change to the favicons tomorrow, and we'll purge the CDN cache after that, so this should be resolved then. Apologies for the inconvenience in the meantime.

Comment: @AdamLear What specific favicons are being changed?

Comment: @SonictheMaskedWerehog Thanks, I've seen that question before posting mine (a little search for avoiding duplicates), it's interesting that in that one the icons are not cut in half, that's why I thought it was a different problem.

Comment: @AdamLear Thanks. Do I delete this question?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado It's up to you. We know we need to kick the cache, but your question may be helpful as a duplicate target in case other reports come up in the meantime. And thank you for reporting this - this is a recurring (and intermittent) issue, but favicon changes are rare, so it's been a low priority and we don't have a way to know if anyone's hit it unless it's pointed out.

Comment: Just leave the question as-is, it will be resolved soon.

Comment: Every time there is a change in the sprites, it breaks for some people, it's due to the kind of server side cache SE choose to use (which is very aggressive and send cached copies even after a change). There is no real fix for that.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I just purged the cache. Are you still seeing broken icons or are they back to normal?

Comment: I'm seeing this still, with ChromEdge on Win 10.

Comment: @AdamLear still incorrect to me (after clearing all my cache, if that makes any difference).

Comment: Ah, my bad, I think I used the wrong cached URLs in my first attempt there. @GerardoFurtado How about now?

Comment: @AdamLear still incorrect... I'm curious: if this is a problem of the CSS sprite's `background` values being incorrect due to the CDN cache, shouldn't you (and everybody else) see the icons the same way I do?

Comment: What's interesting is that the HNQ icons are fine here (meta.se) but broken on all other sites.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado It depends on the CDN node you end up hitting. What happens in our deploy process is that you could hit a web server that has the new cachebreaker and assets, but when the CDN goes to fetch the favicon image so it can cache it, it ends up hitting a webserver that hasn't picked up the new stuff yet, so all the background offsets in the CSS end up wrong. Speaking of which... did another purge today, so hopefully things are back to normal for you.

Comment: @HongOoi Not that interesting, I'm afraid. :) Meta SE serves everything from our servers instead of the CDN, so the issue never comes up.

Comment: @AdamLear yes, everything is looking OK now. Please feel free to clear all these comments.