# Hot Network Questions icons do not match the sites to which they link

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, favicon

A few examples:

[image: A link to a Role-playing Games Stack Exchange site, with the Stack Overflow in Russian icon accompanying it]
(*Stack Overflow in Russian* icon, *[Role-playing Games](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour)* (RPG) Stack Exchange site. [Link](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/206272/enlarge-enlarge-huge-two-different-sources))

[image: A link to the Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange site, with the Information Security icon accompanying it]
(*[Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/tour)* Icon, *[Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour)*. [Link](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/275525/why-couldnt-the-dwarves-beat-kill-the-balrog))

[image]
(*[Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour)* icon, *[Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/tour)* Stack Exchange site. [Link](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/55635/does-a-7000-year-old-ostrich-eggshell-held-at-the-nubian-museum-depict-a-drawing))

These all appeared when I was viewing [this](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/92432/does-art-121-of-the-german-basic-law-require-students-to-be-automatically-gra) question, and I saw other incorrect icons as I visited other SE pages, though incorrect icons neither appeared the same on every SE page I visited nor appeared with respect to the same questions every time.

Comment: Annoying thing here is I know what's wrong (Its happened before) but I can't replicate the issue so I can status review it. I'll be keeping an eye out, and will escalate to staff if I see the same issue (aka, if any regulars see it, point it out).

Comment: Try ctrl+shift+R?

Comment: See [Incorrect icons on hot network questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315468/incorrect-icons-on-hot-network-questions). It's a [known issue](https://drones.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20/62) when a brand new site is launched - [languagedesign.se] just launched today.

Comment: Reopening since the other bug report is wrongly marked as completed. @JourneymanGeek can close again if he disagree with my decision, but that's how I work, since there's no chance staff will notice or do anything with bug report that is completed, hence closing as dupe of it is technically killing any chance to fix the bug.

Comment: Adding to the previous comment, I did try to ask the staff to remove the wrong tag, to no avail, they ignore my comments. Just for fun tried today again. haha

Comment: @Laurel the bug is in the server side cache, which requires manual reset every time a new site is launched. SE never do it, until a bug is reported.

Comment: The tag is correct, @ShadowTheSpringWizard - it was fixed that time. This is a new occasion, so we need to fix it again. This is probably going to be fixed by documenting the need to update the sprites sheet when we build out new sites.

Comment: @Catija no. It fixed that one specific case. Adam says it very clearly in the answer: "But, the core problem remains the same", and: "I'll see if we can dig more into it soonTM". Real fix to the bug is fixing this core problem Adam mentioned, and that was not done, every time new site is launched, someone has to report a bug here, and staff has to kick cache to "fix" this.

Comment: How's it looking now? I am seeing correct icons, so there's unfortunately no way for me to tell if it's fixed or not.

Comment: @AdamLear I've looked through icons on a handful of HNQ lists across multiple sites just now, many of which I knew were correct on-sight, and others I inspected directly to verify. Found no further defects, so from my perspective it's probably fixed, given the drastic reduction in frequency.

Comment: @ADoofus Thanks for confirming, and thanks for the report!

Comment: @AdamLear well, until next site is launched.